# Duplicate database on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a copy of an existing database via a php script on a shared hosting account (specifically Bluehost.com).  I can't get the CREATE DATABASE command to work, I tried a few variations of this script: [How To Programmatically Create MySQL Databases on Shared Linux Hosting Plans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3219799/532887), and the support people say that you can't create a database outside of cpanel.  I'm wondering if this is truly the case or if anyone has a way of doing it.  I can use phpmyadmin to copy the database, but I really need to automate this process so it can be run by a script on the site.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you can check what permissions you have on the database with `show grants for user@host`;

Answer (score 2):

Your user account will not have create database privileges. If it did a rogue customer could create hundreds of databases on the server thus severly impacting performance for themselves and other users.

The cPanel will run the CREATE database on your behalf as a user with sufficient privileges granted to create a database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have to **pay** for another database...[the `CREATE` grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) is likely disabled for customers, or you'd be getting services for free.

Comment: The account comes with unlimited databases, but i'm guessing you're correct in that the 'CREATE' grant is disabled.  However, I could still create the same number of databases...it's just going to be more annoying as a manual process.

Comment: @user532887 - contact your host and explain your requirements.  They **may** make an exception for a single customer if you have an agreement with them in place.  IOW, it's possible for them to grant **just you** with CREATE privs.